# How to hide the image source of an html img tag from web users using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to display a picture using html `img` tag, but the problem is when I click inspect on google chrome it shows me the source:

```
<Img src = "avatar/photo.jpg" alt = "avatar">
```

I want to hide the source information: `avatar/photo.jpg` from webpage viewers who will inspect the page.  Is there is a method to hide this using PHP?

Comment: ... why? you must send the image's content to the client anyhow.

Comment: *"t shows me the source"* - and this being tagged as php, how are you running this off of, a webserver or on your own pc and as `file:///`?

Comment: For publication I know no other method to display the publication photos

Comment: this question's too unclear

Comment: maybe he want use Data URIs? is that it? I really don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: use a rbac so the image is dynamically mapped and not directly accessed

Comment: you can send the byte array data instead. There is no way to really hide it completely

Answer (score 3):

A very simple, if I get your idea correctly, is to use [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64):

```
<Img alt="avatar" src="data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

You will hide the **source** (**link to the avatar**), but there are some tradeoffs in this case:

- increased traffic
- computing the string (serverside)

Answer (score 1):

Directory:

```
- public_html
 - images
  - foo.png
```

When working with URL's you do not need to directly access the file, ie:

```
/images/foo.png
```

You can use something known as a RBAC, or Role Based Access Control. The idea is that the file location is hidden, or not known to the front end user, instead its location is dynamically mapped through a database.

```
tbl_images
 - image_id primary key auto_increment
 - directory_location
 - permission_id

tbl_permissions
 - permission_id primary key auto_increment
 - user_id
 - can_view boolean default 0
```

So now what we have is a way of controlling how the front end user see's the file simply by referencing the model and using a controller:

```
class Image_Controller {
    public function render($image_id) {
        $stmp = SomeDatabaseConnection::getInstance()
            ->prepare('SELECT perm.can_view, img.directory_location, img.permission_id FROM img tbl_images INNER JOIN perm tbl_permissions ON img.permission_id = perm.permission_id WHERE img.image_id = ?');
        $stmp->execute([(int)$image_id]);
        $data = (object) $stmp->fetch();
        if(isset($data->can_view) && $data->can_view) imagepng($data->directory_location);
    }
}
```

So as you can see from the above, assuming our user can access the image and say we have an image with the id of 1 (which the link would look something like /image?id=1) then it would gather the actual location of the image file and display it else the link is useless to the front end user because he don't have the 'permissions' to view it.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to avoid sending the image data and path to the client.  There shouldn't be a problem with letting someone see the HTML source path considering you want to show them the image anyway.

All you can do is obfuscate this data transfer mechanism because at some point the browser must know the path and the image data, and if the browser must know it, the user can know it too.

Comment: I think it's risk ,no?????????????????

Comment: what are you talking about @yastos? try to explain better your question.

Comment: @yastos If you want to post an image on your website the client needs to know where that image is located. If you don't want to say where the image is there won't be an image. Also it's just a path to the image on your server so what would be the risk? Would it help anyone trying to gain access to your server knowing where the avatar of user LW001 is located? Even if that was the case, you would need to let the Browser/Client know where the image is in order to display said image anywhere.

Comment: @LW001 no the image can be dynamically mapped using middleman file to view them, ie /images.php?view=someImageCode .. you can then add permissions using a database, ie if user X is registered he can view it, user C is a guest so the php file will not show that image

Comment: @LW001 Ok thank you i want members to post pictures (publication ex: facebook  ) is what possible to display pictures of members(publication),
Without saving on avatar ?

Comment: @yastos research role base access control, that is what you are looking for

Comment: @KDOT Just my question and the members make publications(pictures) and it will display on the website

Comment: @yastos you simply have a HTML uploader for files and move the file into a directory to upload it and then store that location in the databse following my answer