# How to hide the source of the img when using php/javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, image, performance, base64

I'm trying to design a quiz format website, and as a hint, I want to display the wiki image for the answer. I have the url for the wiki image, but I am afraid that if I set the image source to the wiki image url directly, the user can inspect the page, see the name of the source and deduce the answer, so having the original source is not an option.

I see that [base64 looks promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905119/how-to-hide-the-image-source-of-an-html-img-tag-from-web-users-using-php), but will the impact to page load time be any different than linking the image directly? It sounds like it will definitely increase the size of the page itself (number of characters). Also, can it be done on the fly in php?

Are there any options I can pursue that obfuscate the image source from the user, but don't hamper site performance to a noticeable extent?

Comment: have you tried **decodeURIComponent**   and **encodeURIComponent** ?

Comment: rename image file to something incomprehensible, like a md5hash

Comment: The quizzer could probably do a reverse image search given the want to cheat.

Comment: If the images have a liberal copyright, you could just host them yourself and change the name.